# setupWithViewPager is not exist in tabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

```
public class ActivityManageCustomer extends AppCompatActivity {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage_customer);           
        ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(new AdapterFragmentCustomer(getSupportFragmentManager()));    
        TableLayout tabLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
    }
}
```

setupWithViewPager is not exist in tabLayout

minSdkVersion 14

targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 6, accepted):

import this :

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

and replace this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
```

you are using `TableLayout` which is wrong

Comment: had the same issue, theres a mistake in the code sample here https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Comment: My Tablayout has no title but i dont know how to add it :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change the layout

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout />
```